# How to redirect specific pages to my 404 page?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So simply, I am trying to redirect specific pages to my 404 page.

I am doing this via a regex. Super new to .htaccess and mod_rewrite.

Basically, I am trying to send all pages in a specific format to my 404. For example:

```
http://mydomain.com.au/hello.html?wvsessionid=847180243
http://www.mydomain.com.au/gadfg.html?wvsessionid=dsvf8ya87adfg.744
```

All the above pages should go to my 404 page.

Here is what I came up with, although it doesn't work at all. Doesn't return an internal error or anything, it just lets the pages still be viewed. Not to sure why since I'm still new to regex.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com\.au
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/(wvsessionid)$ /$1.html?wvsessionid=$2 [L,R=404]
```

Does anyone have any idea on how I can fix this to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match against the query string (everything after the `?`) in a rewrite rule. You need to match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` var in a rewrite condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com\.au [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)wvsessionid=
RewriteRule !^/404.html - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: Ahhh, right. Thanks for clearing that up. Code worked perfectly, cheers!

Comment: So if I ever wanted search for something else within my domain, such as `www.mydomain.com.au/anythinghere/uncategorised.html`, would I just replace the `wvsessionid` within your code to `uncategorised`. Or is it more complex than that?

Comment: @fizzix the "uncategorised.html" bit isn't the query string, so you can't replace the match against the query string with that. It's part of the URI so you want the regex to be part of the rewrite rule.

Comment: Could you provide an example if possible?

Comment: @fizzix `RewriteRule /uncategorised.html - [L,R=404]`